# How to query multiple API endpoints using GraphQL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and want to query multiple endpoints from the following API: https://docs.thecatapi.com/. To get started I want to query just one of the endpoints using GraphQL but can not seem to find or figure out the correct syntax to make the request successful.
My code so far:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var body = @"query {
                        name: string,
                        description: string,
                        temperament: string,
                        wikipedia_url: string
                    }";

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds?attach_breed=0");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/graphql");
        request.AddHeader("MY-API-KEY", "DEMO-API-KEY");
        request.AddParameter("application/graphql", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

The reponse:
[image]

I have tried multiple google searches and not found what am I looking and would be grateful for a hand.

Comment: is this api even a graphql api?

Comment: @Lewis Taylor - I'm not quite quite sure I understand, the API itself is a public service api that basically returns data about cats. I wanted to use GraphQL to query it if thats even possible.

Comment: @FemiDokun I'm afraid you've made a wrong concept with graphql. As I learnt [here](with different input), graphQl can make your api support some features like expose only one endpoint and  return custom result with different input. That's why Lewis asked if the cat api is a graphql api.

Answer (score 0):

An API has to support GraphQL in order for you to query it using GraphQL.
In this case https://docs.thecatapi.com/ is not a GraphQL API, therefore you cannot query it using GraphQL.

There are a few GraphQL enabled APIs online you could learn with, I've not used any personally, but they are a search away.